# Where can I find Date when the Quote was Won (Date Won field)

Tags: dynamics-crm

In CRM 2015, where can I find the Date Won field of a Quote that appears when we Create Order (close the quote as Won). I can see it on the window when I Create Order. But in the backend, I'm not able to locate the field.

Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recheck Quote Won activity that is created once quote is won.

Comment: Thanks.I checked the Quote Close entity. I found 'Actual End' is exactly the field I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the CrmServiceClient to close the quote here's some VB.NET code to achieve that:

```
    'Win the quote
    Dim winQuoteRequest As New WinQuoteRequest() With {
         .QuoteClose = New QuoteClose() With {
             .QuoteId = thisQuote.ToEntityReference(),
             .Subject = "Quote Closed (Won - " & wonStatus & "),
             .ActualEnd = Now(),
             .Description = winOrLoseReason
         },
         .Status = New OptionSetValue(statusCode)
    }

    crmClient.Execute(winQuoteRequest)
```

The ActualEnd field is shown in the "Closed Date" field in the Close Quote activity.